# Limit at infinity for sequence $ n^2x(1-x^2)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity, geometric-series

I'm supposed to prove that this sequence goes to zero as n goes to infinity.

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {n^2x (1-x^2)^n}, \mathrm{where~} 0 \le x \le 1$$

I've been trying a few things (geometric formula, rewriting $(1-x^2)^n$ as $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k x^{2k} $) and messing around with that. But I can't seem to get anywhere. I could be missing something key that I've forgotten. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: No hypothesis for $x$?

Comment: The x is something of a red herring. So is the use of n. Replace n by y. Now you have something like y^2 exp(-k y). It is well-known and easy to prove that exponentials always outpace polynomials ...

Comment: That sequence of functions goes to zero pointwise, but not uniformly. It is best to make clear what "goes to zero" really means here.

Comment: An idea could be to see that $2x$ would be the inner derivative, so it's integral may be easier to consider. Hope I'm not being too tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x=0$ or $x=1$ it is trivial, so $0<x<1$. Define $a=1-x^2$, then $0<a<1$.

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2x(1-x^2)^n = x\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2a^n \le \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2a^n = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(1/a)^n} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2n}{\ln(1/a)(1/a)^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{\ln^2(1/a)(1/a)^n}=\frac{2}{\ln^2(1/a)}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a^n=0$$

Using l'Hopital twice and the fact that $0 < a < 1$.

Also all of the terms in the sequence are positive, $0\le\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2x(1-x^2)^n\le 0$.

Comment: $0\le\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2x(1-x^2)\le 0$?

Comment: It's greater than or equal to zero because every element in the sequence is greater than or equal to zero, and it's less than or equal to zero because it's less than or equal to a limit that converges to zero. EDIT: Oh oops. I forgot the exponent $n$. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: what happens here $\frac{2\ln(n)}{n}+\ln(a)=0+\ln(a)$? are you saying that $\frac{2\ln(n)}{n}=0$?

Comment: I meant to say that it approaches zero, but now that you mention it I'm not sure that that's valid. I edited it to something more valid.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, it seems that there was an edit to the question so that I 9 years ago accidentally have answered what was not the final question.

This is now instead an answer to show that $x(1-x^2)^n$ will be 0 as $n\to\infty$

and **not** for $n^2x(1-x^2)^n$

For an answer to the question as it currently is stated I will recommend you to look at Juan or Jacks answers for that question which look sound. The Rudin theorem in Juan's answer can be phrased in engineering math terms : "exponentials grow faster than potences". Therefore I would probably personally have taken the Rudin route for that problem.

---

First let us observe that $x(1-x^2)^n$ is smaller than $(1-x^2)^n$ on the interval, since $|x|<1$.

The largest point of $(1-x^2)$ is at $x=0$ which is $1$ and the smallest is $0$ at $x=1$ (easy to check) and monotonically decreasing. So the function $(1-x^2)^n$ will be bounded by 1. Any $f(x_0) = (1-{x_0}^2)^n$ will decrease exponentially with $n$ for any $x_0\neq 0$ so the crossing $y=\epsilon>0$ will be pushed towards 0 with increasing $n$. So we see that the function $(1-x^2)^n$ will shrink towards $0$ for all values on the interval, except for $x=0$, but as our function of interest is actually $x$ times the function we investigated, so it will of course be even more suppressed.

Comment: Isn't the largest point of $(1-x^2)$ at $x=0$?

Comment: Oh, yep you are right. I wonder what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

This one's example 7.6 on Rudin's wonderful book Principles Of Mathematical Analysis. He solves it by "Theorem 3.20(b)", which states that "If $p>0$, and $\alpha$ is real, then $lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}=0$. ", so you need to rewrite $f_{n}(x)$ in that form.

Ignore $x$ and put $n^{2}(1-x^2)^{n}=\frac{n^\alpha}{(1+p)^n}$, clearly $\alpha = 2$ and $(1+p)^n (1-x^2)^n = 1$, take the $n$th root on both sides (you can take the positive root, since you need a value that works for both even and odd n), so with a little bit of algebra you can show that $p = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2}$ fits the bill, since $0<x<1$ implies that $p = \frac{x^2}{1-x^2} > 0$, so indeed, by theorem 3.20(b) we have:

$lim_{n\to\infty}n^2 x(1-x^2)^n = x lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^2}{(1+\frac{x^2}{1-x^2})^n}=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f_n(x) = x(1-x^2)^n $$
is a positive function on $(0,1)$. By computing $f_n'$, it is easy to check that $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}$ is the only stationary point of $f_n(x)$ over $(0,1)$, hence:
$$ 0 \leq f_n(x) \leq f_n\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n+1}}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^n\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2en}}.$$
Moreover, $f_n(x)$ is exponentially small on the interval $\left[\frac{1}{n^{1/3}},1\right]$.

By putting all together, we have that $n^2 f_n(x)$ is a sequence of functions that pointwise converge to the zero function on $[0,1]$. Pointwise but not uniformly, also because:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} n^2 f_n(x)\,dx = \frac{n^2}{2n+2}\to +\infty.$$

Comment: @Bungo: uniform convergence to zero of the $f_n$s, sure, but the original problem deals with $n^2\cdot f_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach is as follows.  Let $z=\left|\log(1-x^2)\right|$.  Then, we have for $x(1-x) \ne 0$

$$\begin{align}
n^2x(1-x^2)^{n}&=n^2xe^{n\log(1-x^2)}\\\\
&=\frac{n^2x}{e{nz}}\\\\
&=\frac{n^2x}{1+nz+\frac12 n^2z^2+\frac16 n^3z^3+O(n^4)}
\end{align}$$

which clearly approaches $0$ as $n \to \infty$.  And we are done as the limit is $0$ for $x=0$ and $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=0$ or $x=1$ we are done so you can assume that $1>x>0.$ Then $0<1-x^2<1.$

Now put $p:=\dfrac{x^2}{1-x^2}.$ For $n\geqslant4$ we have 
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1+p)^n&>\binom{n}{3}p^3\\\\&=\dfrac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}p^3\\\\&>\dfrac{(n/2)(n/2)(n/2)}{3!}p^3\\\\&=\dfrac{n^3\cdot p^3}{48} 
\end{aligned}
$$
and hence $n^2x(1-x^2)^n=\dfrac{n^2x}{(1+p)^n}\;<\;\dfrac{48x}{p^3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}$ and since $\dfrac{48x}{p^3}\cdot\dfrac{1}{n}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2x(1-x^2)^n=0.$$

In general, you can prove that given any real number $\alpha$ and any real $a\in(0,1)$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^\alpha a^n=0$ using a similar argument.