# Function limit of monomial.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

This is a modified version of [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452535/limit-at-infinity-for-sequence-n2x1-x2n/1452565#1452565).

What is the limit of
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} {(3/2)^n (1-x^2)^n},\  \mathrm{where~}\  0 \le x \le 1?$$

Does it approximate any specific well-known function? If so, does this approach have any relations to other methods of generating or approximating the same function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$(3/2)^n(1-x^2)^n=\left(\frac{3-3x^2}{2}\right)^n$$What are the possible values of $\lim_{n\to\infty}y^n$ for a fixed $y>0$?